# How to zip tuples into columns without losing type information

Tags: python, typing

I'd like to zip fields of a list of tuples into columns. However, this operation loses the types.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class MyTuple(NamedTuple):
    one: int
    two: str

one, two = zip(*[MyTuple(i, str(i)) for i in range(100)])
```

PyCharm's type checker does no longer know that `one` and `two` are integers and strings. Is there a way to do this without losing types?

Comment: Tried on my PyCharm setup and, same as you, it's clever enough to track the types through zipping and/or transposing. Maybe you need to give it the right type hints.

Comment: I'd be ok with writing a new function `as_columns`. However, it is not obvious which type signature to write.

Comment: `Tuple[Iterable[int], Iterable[str]]` should do

Comment: This type signature only works for a single type of tuple. It won't work for other combinations and lengths.

Answer (score 0):

`one` is (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 100)
and `two` is ('1', '2', '3', '4', ..., '100')

therefore, type of both `one` and `two` is tuple.

if you write `type(one[0])` then it might be okay.

Comment: My problem was that I'd like to know the types before runtime.